# CORS error playing mp3 from another website

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-audio

I have the problem that my React application does not play audio from another source with a CORS error.
Sample: https://audio.podigee-cdn.net/1041740-m-0fcf92e897e7cd93200a43cf103a75fb.mp3

Weirdly enough when I go to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp, enter the url from above and click play it works.

On my local React application I get a 302 status and a redirect subsequently.The audio tag contains a crossOrigin="anonymous" and the url in the src element.

On W3Schools it does somehow the redirect and I only get a status 206 from the redirected url.

How to reproduce:

1. git clone https://github.com/SamTV12345/PodFetch.git
2. Follow the README description in the Building section
3. git checkout origin/develop
4. Add any podcast with more than 5 episodes.
5. Click on the CloudIcon

Comment: Please do not ask "how do I do X?", if you are actually trying to figure out what is wrong with a specific attempt to do X. Those are different kinds of questions with different information requirements. If you want to know how to play the file, then you should be focused on explaining an exact *specification* for what the code needs to do. If you are trying to fix the code in the React application, we can only possibly comment on code that is actually shown to us; please read [mre].

Comment: I did exactly that and Stackoverflow didn't let me post my question. But as soon as I added "How to" to the title it worked. Seems like a bad validation on the backend.

Comment: There are a variety of automated quality checks. Usually there are better ways to work around them. We don't control how they work.

Comment: I could now edit my question to the one I was planning to put into the heading.

Comment: This is better suited for Webmasters site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the mp3 URL through `new Audio(url)` instead of `XMLHttpRequest` to avoid CORS. For example :

```js
class PlaySound extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      play: false
    };

    this.url = "https://audio.podigee-cdn.net/1041740-m-0fcf92e897e7cd93200a43cf103a75fb.mp3";
    this.audio = new Audio(this.url);
    this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
  }

  togglePlay() {
    const wasPlaying = this.state.play;
    this.setState({
      play: !wasPlaying
    });

    if (wasPlaying) {
      this.audio.pause();
    } else {
      this.audio.play();
      setInterval(()=>{
        console.clear();
        let seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
        let points = '.'.repeat(seconds % 4);
        console.log(`Loading audio${points}`);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          id="audioBtn"
          onClick={this.togglePlay} onCanPlay={this.detectPlay}> {this.state.play ? "Pause" : "Play"}
          
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PlaySound />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

Example occurrence of CORS with using Ajax:

```js
let audio = document.querySelector('#myAudio');

function playAudio() { 
  audio.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
  audio.pause(); 
} 

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://audio.podigee-cdn.net/1041740-m-0fcf92e897e7cd93200a43cf103a75fb.mp3',
  success: (res) => {
    audio.srcObject = URL.createObjectURL(res);
  },
  error: (err) => {
    console.error('CORS Error. See browser console for detail.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio id="myAudio"></audio>

<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>
```

Comment: did you try to import cors and call in your component?

Comment: @BivishanSapkota No, I didn't need to import cors